# Receiving null exception when using MEF import in a class library "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mef

I am experiencing a strange issue when trying to use the import MEF paradigm in a c# class library project. Basically I have another DLL which has the implementation for IDevicePreferences. When calling devicePreferences.Callsign I receive the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

devicePreferences was null.
```

I am embedding this class library project in a DLL which is used in my other project. In other words I am trying to do MEF in a class library via instantiating a WeatherClient object in a standard C# .Net project which has the DLL. (My Project -> My Class Library -> IDevicePreferences DLL)

Interestingly, I am able to implement the IDevicePreferences interface in my project (I have the DLL for that there as well) without issue. But I can't get it to work from *inside* my class Library / WeatherClient class.

Here is the WeatherClient class:

```cs
public class WeatherClient
{
    [Import(typeof(IDevicePreferences))]
    public IDevicePreferences devicePreferences;

    public WeatherClient(String serverIp, int port)
    {
        this.serverIp = serverIp;
        this.port = port;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("callsign: " + devicePreferences.Callsign);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you create/import WeatherClient?

Comment: @Vernou I am using a simple constructor approach: `WeatherClient weatherClient = new WeatherClient(serverIp, port)` Is that problematic?

Comment: Yes, because you don't call MEF. The field `devicePreferences` isn't filled and is null. Finally, `devicePreferences.Callsign` throw `NullReferenceException`. You need call `CompositionContainer.ComposeParts` on WeatherClient instance to fill the field `devicePreferences`.

Comment: Got it thank you, just started learning MEF.

Comment: hmm I only see `Compose(CompositionBatch batch);` not `ComposeParts` It must be the version I am using, I'll research this. Thanks again.